# how to display html table in exact same format in outlook email-Python

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a html file with this grey format.

[image]

I would like to send this in outlook email. I write the data from dataframe into above formatted table into html file.

Next step, I am trying to read this file "data.html" whih is in above table format

```
report_file = open("data.html")
html_table = report_file.read()
```

But I am ending up with below format.  How do i keep the same format like above?

[image]

The source for my table is from

https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/make-html-tables-with-pandas/?doing_wp_cron=1655562539.7324590682983398437500

Comment: as I remeber dataframe can get some options to add CSS values to HTML. OR you can use pure Python ot generate HTML with CSS on your own. HTML is only a string.

Comment: email may not respect some CSS values, and values may have to be directly in tags as `style="..."`